# Suggestions for concise class model / pattern to solve multiple minor-variations in methods

Tags: java, php, design-patterns, web-applications

I have a bunch of database reports I need to implement, and there will be more in the future, so am especially interested in building extensible code and avoiding duplicated logic and code.  I am implementing in PHP, but the question is more general.  Feel free to post examples in Java, C++, C#, etc. in addition to PHP.

The problem I face is that the reports are just enough different that I can't easily combine all the code for building the SQL, and even more difficultly, building the HTML output.  For example, one report contains a column of long text messages, which need to be CSS-styled and Javascript-enabled to make mouseovers show the whole message, while others have columns where the values are converted to percentages, or conditionally displayed as "less than 1%" and accumulated into an "other" category.

So I started by using a strategy pattern.  A very simple sketch of my class model can be seen here:  http://static.inky.ws/image/4044/ClassDiagram.png

I have an abstract Report, and a concrete implementation for each report type.  Reports have a couple of attributes which reference encapsulated functionality (via concrete implementations of interfaces) for the differing SQL builder and output data formatting for each report.  But this starts to look like way too many classes per report.  Is there another, better way to approach this?

Sketch of the code to implement the model referenced above:

```
<?php
abstract class Report {
   private $sqlBuilder = null;
   private $dataFormatter = null;
}

class ReportOne extends Report {
   public function __constructor() {
       $this->sqlBuilder = new ReportOneSqlBuilder();
       $this->dataFormatter = new ReportOneDataFormatter();
}
class ReportTwo extends Report {
   // similar to ReportOne
}

interface SqlBuilder {
}
class ReportOneSqlBuilder implements SqlBuilder {
}
class ReportTwoSqlBuilder implements SqlBuilder {
}

interface DataFormatter {
}
class ReportOneDataFormatter {
}
class ReportTwoDataFormatter {
}
?>
```

The idea is keep all the common code in the abstract class, and the specific differences in the various concrete child classes.  It just occurred to me writing this that I need abstract classes for the SQL and data formatting as well, since the interfaces can't really carry any implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is better to keep two things that are sort of similar but have important differences, completely separate from each other, even if this is against the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) principle.

There are in fact good reasons for this. Importantly, if you attempt to reuse certain parts of the code, and later on you need to modify something that will affect only one of the reports, you will have to break that common code anyway.

Design patterns are cute and certainly have their uses, however, in some cases it is better to use a different logic that might partially repeat itself, and keep the code as simple as possible. Something even more important than DRY is code readability, if you complexify your code for a feature that really doesn't need to be complex, you will hurt your readability for little to no gain.

If you really think these two reports have strong similarities and it's worth complexifying your application, or if you do this to practice your design pattern implementation skills, go for it. If you simply want to get the job done efficiently and make your application easy to modify later on, just keep it simple and use two different logics.

Comment: Good points, and that's pretty much what I'm struggling with.  Probably 90% to 95% of the code is duplicated across my existing 3 reports.  I will likely need to add a 4th in the near future.  Hence my desire to be DRY.  :-)

Comment: If it really is 90% to 95% of the code that is duplicated, then it is worth fixing it. Though it's a little hard to help you design it with little context.

Comment: How can I help provide the context you need?  What would you like to know or see?